# How to insert more than two Select Sql inside the same cursor.execute?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

How to insert more than two Select Sql inside the same cursor.execute? I incorrectly write my code. For example in this function:

```
def example(event=None):
  
    cursor.execute('SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc = 435',
                   'SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc = 436',
                   'SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc = = 437')  

    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    example['value'] = result
    example.current(0)
    return result
```

Comment: Check if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584640/suggested-way-to-run-multiple-sql-statements-in-python

Comment: @basha04 I don't think I understand. I'm just starting out with Python. The solution would be to add cursor.execute ()? It seems too easy to me.

Comment: Use `IN` -     `cursor.execute('SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc IN (X,Y,Z)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's interest of multiplying querys instead of making one query containing the datas your are looking for ?

In your case :

```
SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc IN (435,436,437)
```

i can't see any interest to make more than one query in that case.    if you use the query i gave to you, you just have to browse the results one by one with the cursor.

```
query = "SELECT aaaaaa From bbbbbb WHERE cccccc IN (435,436,437)"
cursor.execute(query)
result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
```

however if you really want to execute multi statements, you can use the param "multi=True".
Here is the doc who explain how to do : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

```
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
    ...
```

Comment: In this case, do I use 435, 436, 437 at the same time? I would need to use them individually, separately, that is, one at a time, taken individually and not together. In short, filtered. As you wrote, are they taken individually when I have to use them? Thanks

Comment: i have edited my answer, i hope it will help